# I want to rename multiple files in a directory in Linux based on the delimeter

Tags: sed, file-rename

I need help to rename multiple files in a directory based on the delimeter.

Sample:

From
R01235-XYZ-TRAIL.PDF

TO

R01234-TRAIL.PDF

and

From

XYZ-C12345-TRAIL.PDF

TO

C12345-TRAIL.PDF

is it possible to delete based on - delimeter?

I am not specifically removing XYZ but rather remove anything before the first - and the middle occurence between two -.. XYZ is just a representation of the characters in that field.

Thanks!

I tried SED, LS, MV, I also tried RENAME but it seems not working for me.

Comment: In your first example, you are removing the 2nd "delimited by -" field, while in the 2nd example you deleting the first "field". Are you really try to get rid of any occurancce of XYZ regardless of where it is in the filename? DONT answer in comments but DO update your question with this clarification. ALSO include your best attempt (in your estimation) of the code (`sed` I would think) for solving this. Good luck.

Comment: I tried sed using wildcard but it did not work ☹️

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
rename -n 's/XYZ-//' file
```

This removes `XYZ-` from the file name.

If this meets your requirements, remove the `-n` option for the renaming to take place.

On retrospect, perhaps:

```
rename -n 's/([A-Z][0-9]{5}-).*-/$1/;s/^.*-([A-Z][0-9]{5}-)/$1/' file
```

With sed:

```
sed -E 's/^([A-Z][0-9]{5}-).*-|^.*([A-Z][0-9]{5}-.*)/mv & \1\2/' file
```

Check the results and then:

```
sed -E 's/^([A-Z][0-9]{5}-).*-|^.*([A-Z][0-9]{5}-.*)/mv & \1\2/' file | sh
```

Comment: I previously tried rename command but seems nothing happened. Also, XYZ is just a representation, it could be another string so a wildcard entry should be used.But ill still try your suggestion. Thanks

Comment: @LexLuthor note that there are two versions of `rename`: https://github.com/tldr-pages/tldr/issues/3125

Comment: I tried rename as suggested but got this instead